# Multiple tables in one model - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

My Index page uses 3 tables in the database:

- index_slider
- index_feature
- footer_boxes

I use one controller (IndexController.php) and call the three models like so:

```
public function index() { 
return View::make('index')
->with('index_slider', IndexSlider::all())
->with('index_feature', IndexFeature::all())
->with('footer_boxes', FooterBoxes::all()); 
}
```

The three **models** above need *::all()* data, so they are all setup like this:

```
class IndexSlider extends Eloquent {
public $table ='index_slider';
}
```

**note:** *class name changes for each model*

Seeing as my index page requires these 3 tables and the fact I am repeating the syntax in each model then should I be using polymorphic relations or setting this up differently? ORM from what I have read should have 1 model for each table, but I can't help but feel this would be silly in my situation and many others. DRY (don't repeat yourself) looses meaning in a sense.

What would be the best approach to take here or am I on the right track?

Comment: ORM does 'need' a class for each table. 
Only use polymorfism if the classes have something in common. 
It's not because you use 3 models in one view that you should put all these models together. That has nothing to do with each other...
I'd say you are on the right track but you seem to be needing some more reading on basic MVC structure

Comment: Thanks for your response. If not polymorfism, then would **One To Many** be an alternative approach? I have been adopting MVC structure more recently, so you're right, I will look into it some more and get more of an understanding.

Comment: CRUD has nothing to do with MVC pattern

Comment: @tereško CRUD? sorry, can you elaborate on this? is this the main use for One To Many? I want to integrate CRUD patter into later version on my app. I have decided to user query builder instead of involving eloquent and more models, it seemed like a better option. Your thoughts?

Comment: CRUD stands for Create Read Update Delete. For a simple example, if your webapp is a blog, it should be able to Create, Read, Update and Delete blogposts. What teresko wants to say is that I advised you to read on the MVC pattern, while you more likely need to read about CRUD (in addition to MVC ;) ). This will explain why you would want a model for each of these things. I think you are confusing and misusing a lot of terms. One to Many is a relationship between database tables, so it's not applicable to your case of an index page (a view) using 3 models (representing database tables).

Comment: *polymorphism ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly I should say each model is written for a specific table, you can't squeeze three tables into one model unless they are related. [See Here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)

There are two ways I would go about making your code more DRY.
Instead of passing your data in a chain of withs I would pass it as the second parameter in your make:

```
public function index() { 
    $data = array(
        'index_slider'  => IndexSlider::all(),
        'index_feature' => IndexFeature::all(),
        'footer_boxes'  => FooterBoxes::all(),
    );

    return View::make('index', $data);
}
```

Passing data as the second parameter. [See here](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views)

The other way I would go about it, and this is a better solution if your application is going to grow large, is to create a service (another model class but not hooked up to eloquent) that when you call will return the necessary data. I would definitely do it this way if you are returning the above data in multiple views.

An example of using a service would look something like this:

```
<?php 
// app/models/services/indexService.php
namespace Services;

use IndexSlider;
use IndexFeature;
use FooterBoxes;

class IndexService
{
    public function indexData()
    {
        $data = array(
            'index_slider'  => IndexSlider::all(),
            'index_feature' => IndexFeature::all(),
            'footer_boxes'  => FooterBoxes::all(),
        );

        return $data;
    }
}
```

and your controller:

```
<?php
// app/controllers/IndexController.php

use Services/IndexService;

class IndexController extends BaseController
{
    public function index() { 
        return View::make('index', with(new IndexService())->indexData());
    }
}
```

This service can be expanded with a lot less specific methods and you should definitely change the naming (from IndexService and indexData to more specific class/method names).

If you want more information on using Services I wrote a cool article about it [here](http://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services)

Hope this helps!