# One model to several tables Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have MySQL database tables, of which names are in "yyyymmdd" format. I need to select several tables, for example, from "20150901" to "20150930". I think there might be a way to implement only one model for those tables.

If somebody knows how to do so, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of 1 model for many tables why not using a parent model ,create a scope for the date search and extend that parent with your tables ?

Comment: Hope this link may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576027/laravel-4-can-one-model-serve-several-db-tables  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119118/multiple-tables-in-one-model-laravel

Comment: if those other 2 tables has a relation with the model, and that relationship is many to many, try looking at pivot tables

Comment: Thanks, @Gal. Would you explain more in detail? I don't know what _scope_ means.

Comment: Thanks, @VijaySankhat. But those are not my case. I need to set table's name dynamically as user wants. For example, if I want to see data of 23th of September, the table name should be set to "20150923".

Comment: Only one table will be used or more than one table in the query?

Comment: @HumbleLearner I got the question wrong,it wont help you (if you still want to learn - [query scope](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes)) the main issue here is your table structure as instead of creating multiple tables you should've just added a date column.The first link Vijay gave you should do the trick,if you need to change the name after model initial you may want to try the `setTable` method as offered in the same topic.

Comment: @VijaySankhat, I want to import several tables, for example last 30 days (which means 30 tables), or last 7 days (which means 7 tables).

Comment: @Gal, I've already tried `setTable`, but it does not change table name.

Answer (score 1):

> immagine that this is your model.

```
class XYZ extends Eloquent {
  public function __construct($table, array $attributes = array()){
     parent::__construct($attributes);
     $this->table = $table;
   }
}
```

> and you have 7 tables suppose for 1 week.
>   then inside controller loop you can have like

```
$reportData = array();
foreach($tables as $table) {
    $xyzObj = new XYZ($table);
    $reportData[] =  $xyzObj->get();
    //add your query stuff here like where and fetching records
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I got the following error. `BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 823:
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $table ]] in class App\Http\Models\Log`

Comment: It seems your table is NULL see the log App\Http\Models\Log

Comment: print all the tables to see are there any tables

Comment: Thanks for your eager response. But as I said, I got error. It doesn't work :(

Comment: Please Paste your tables loop here

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. I added a function to the Models\Log class. take a look at the following code. `public function getData($table_name){  return DB::table($table_name)->get(); }`  How do you think? Is it a good way coding in Laravel?

Comment: Do you get the $table_name? have you checked?

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: yes. I verified that the $table_name is set correctly and the `getData()` function works well. What I want to ask is whether that is correct MVC method. I use Laravel 5.1

Comment: Try using Eloquent way, my solution will work fine with Eloquent way. if you want to see your query statement try this, DB::enableQueryLog(); //your code and then var_dump(DB::getQueryLog());